# How to develop Embeddable Widgets using Angular 2 for 3rd party sites

Tags: angular, widget

I'm not sure if this is possible in Angular 2, but,

I want to know if there is any way/approach/support for developing embeddable widgets which can be integrated into other websites that perform certain functionality.

For example, a small piece of source code that generates a button on the 3rd party website. Clicking on this button generates some popup windows performing some actions contacting our web server.

Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: You can go with the iframe, but not sure how far you can go.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @Igor Jankovic. I came across this option during my search for answers. I'll keep you posted after trying this out.

Comment: @Sam hey, how did this work out for you?

Comment: @Yeysides, I haven't done it. So this is a still an open question. As discussed above, one way of achieving it is through iframes, however, from my research I understood is it will be tricky if you try to integrate some source (which might use jquery for handling any actions) into angular 2 application. Another case is, if you embed any angular source of one version into another angular application of different version, there is a chance of conflicts. I haven't really tried it but these are some scenario's I have determined which needs to be tried out practically. Hope these insights help you.

Answer (score 5):

Have you heard of Angular Elements? It was introduced in Angular 6. The scenario that you're referring to sounds like a perfect use case for Angular Elements.

> Angular elements are Angular components packaged as custom elements, a web standard for defining new HTML elements in a framework-agnostic way.

So just think of them as self-contained widgets, that will play quite nicely with any of your web apps built on any framework/library.

Have a look at this enlightening [NGCONF Talk by Rob Wormald on Angular Elements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1gLFPLVJjY). You can find several tutorials on creating an Angular Element. Here's another one by [Jeff Delaney from AngularFirebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4u9_kdkvTsc).

Angular's Official Website also has a very nice and easy to understand example that you can have a look at [here](https://angular.io/guide/elements#example-a-popup-service).

Hope this helps.